# can I create a PDF form that will export the questions and answers to an excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I want to create a form for my office that asks new clients several questions.  I then want to export the filled out form to an existing excel sheet that has all of my clients' names and contact info on it.  I need the form to export the answers to the correct column in my excel sheet because other programs I use will only import contact data if it is entered in a specific excel sheet.

Is there a way to tell Adobe which column to put the info that clients enter?

Comment: If its possible it wouldn't be with the default features of Excel or Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps to achieve what you need.

1. Open Adobe Acrobat.
2. From the "Forms" menu select the "Start Form wizard"
3. Select the third option - "No existing form" and click "Next"
   [image]
4. Adobe live cycle designer will open with "New form assistant" window
   [image]
5. Select the option "Use a Blank form" and click "Next"
6. A Blank form opens - create the form as you need it
   *Note: For my case as example - I used Conference registration template*
   [image]
7. Then once you are done with creating the form - Select File->Save - save this in any location on your PC.
8. Now creation of form is complete - you can email the form (or send a link of the forms location) to all your clients
9. Once they fill the form and click on "Submit form" in the .pdf files you sent - the system will initiate an email to your inbox (or whichever email ID was specified)
10. Once the email is sent from your clients - you will receive it and when you open it Adobe will promote to create a responses file.
11. Update the responses file by selecting the appropriate options.
12. Now this file is the collection of all the responses received from your various clients. On the left hand side of the window - there is an option to "Export" - select CSV as type when exporting
13. Open the file with excel - now all the data entered by your clients are available in excel
14. If required - you can use `vlookup` formula to extract information from this .csv file

    Comment if you have any specific questions

> Written with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/).